# my array of pointers is not saving and returns wrong output after the do while loop

Tags: c

```
int main ()
{
    char *temp_list[4096];
    char *list[4096];
    char *token;
    int countries;
    ssize_t rd_countries;
    char buf[512];
    size_t nbytes;
    char *file_name = "AllCountries.dat";
    int temp = 0;   
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    countries = open(file_name,O_RDONLY);
    nbytes = sizeof(buf);

    // start of do while to read through the list and set tokens to
    // the array list the file is separated by commas 
    //and have to use the open function (nothing else)

    do {                                                  
    rd_countries = read(countries, buf, nbytes);    
    token = strtok_r(buf, ",",temp_list);
        while (token != NULL){                  
            temp_list[i] = token;
            printf("%s\n  |||||||||||  ", temp_list[i]);
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok_r(NULL, ",",temp_list);
        i = i + 1;
        }                                   
    printf("-----------");
    }while (rd_countries != 0);

    //here is where i see whats in the temp list but everything is wrong

    for (j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    printf("The temp list: %s\n", temp_list[j]);
    } 
//  for(int k = 0; k < 4096; k++){
//  if (k == 1 || k == 2 || k == 8 || k == 9) {
//  list[k] = temp_list[k];
//      }
//  }

//239 countries biggest country is 44 char long
return 0;

}
```

here is some of the output:

```
##outputs
  |||||||||||  URY
Uruguay
  |||||||||||  Uruguay
South America
  |||||||||||  South America
South America
  |||||||||||  South America
175016
  |||||||||||  175016
1828
  |||||||||||  1828
3337000
  |||||||||||  3337000
75.2
  |||||||||||  75.2
20831
  |||||||||||  20831
Uruguay
  |||||||||||  Uruguay
Republic
  |||||||||||  Republic
Jorge Batlle Ib��ez
  |||||||||||  Jorge Batlle Ib��ez
3492
  |||||||||||  3492
UY
23
  |||||||||||  UY
23
VEN
  |||||||||||  VEN
Venezuela
  |||||||||||  Venezuela
South America
  |||||||||||  South America
South America
  |||||||||||  South America
912050
  |||||||||||  912050
1811
  |||||||||||  1811
24170000
  |||||||||||  24170000
73.1
  |||||||||||  73.1
95023
  |||||||||||  95023
Venezuela
  |||||||||||  Venezuela
Federal Republic
  |||||||||||  Federal Republic
Hugo Ch�vez Fr�as
  |||||||||||  Hugo Ch�vez Fr�as
3539
  |||||||||||  3539
VE
nz�lez Macchi
  |||||||||||  VE
nz�lez Macchi
-----------a Corazao
  |||||||||||  a Corazao
-----------The temp list: 
The temp list: a Corazao
The temp list: a Corazao
The temp list: azao
The temp list: o
The temp list: 0
The temp list: PE
152
The temp list: 2
The temp list: SUR
The temp list: h America
The temp list: 1.4
The temp list: ame
The temp list: epublic
The temp list: c
The temp list: nald Venetiaan
The temp list: n
The temp list: SR
31
The temp list: ay
The temp list: h America
The temp list: rica
The temp list: h America
The temp list: rica
The temp list: 175016
The temp list: 337000
The temp list: .2
The temp list: 
The temp list: ublic
The temp list: orge Batlle Ib��ez
The temp list:  Batlle Ib��ez
The temp list: Ib��ez
The temp list: 3492
The temp list: Venezuela
The temp list: ela
The temp list: outh America
The temp list: rica
The temp list: South America
The temp list: h America
The temp list: 1811
The temp list: 0000
The temp list: 3
The temp list: nezuela
The temp list: a
The temp list: deral Republic
The temp list: ublic
The temp list: ugo Ch�vez Fr�as
The temp list: s
The temp list: VE
nz�lez Macchi
The temp list: �lez Macchi
The temp list: hi
The temp list: 85
The temp list: 
27
The temp list:  America
The temp list: South America
The temp list: ica
The temp list: 285216
The temp list: 1821
The temp list: 
The temp list: 0
The temp list: 
The temp list: ublic
The temp list: 
The temp list: ntin Paniagu�����
The temp list: niagu�����
The temp list: �����
The temp list: a Corazao
The temp list: razao
The temp list: PE
152
The temp list: R
The temp list: h America
The temp list: rica
The temp list: 63265
The temp list: 5
The temp list: riname
The temp list: Republic
The temp list:  Venetiaan
The temp list: aan
The temp list: 243
The temp list: 1
The temp list: RY
The temp list: uguay
The temp list: th America
The temp list: a
The temp list: 00
The temp list: .2
The temp list: 31
The temp list: ruguay
The temp list: y
The temp list: lic
The temp list: e Ib��ez
The temp list: 
The temp list: 
The temp list: EN
The temp list: nezuela
The temp list: la
The temp list: rica
The temp list: h America
The temp list: 2050
The temp list: 1811
The temp list: 170000
The temp list: 00
```

Comment: Can you please somehow provide the file please?

Comment: its a long file i can post some of it if you want

Comment: 115,DZA,Algeria,Africa,Northern Africa,2381741,1962,31471000,69.7,49982,Al-Jazair/Algérie,Republic,Abdelaziz Bouteflika,35,DZ
146,AGO,Angola,Africa,Central Africa,1246700,1975,12878000,38.3,6648,Angola,Republic,José Eduardo dos Santos,56,AO
94,BEN,Benin,Africa,Western Africa,112622,1960,6097000,50.2,2357,Bénin,Republic,Mathieu Kérékou,187,BJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a read() from a file the buffer is not necessarily terminated by a \0. you need to make the contents of buf a null terminated string in order for strtok to process it.

E.g. as Iharob pointed out you can do something like

```
rd_countries = read(countries, buf, nbytes-1);
if (rd_countries>-1)
{
  buf[rd_countries] = '\0';
}
```

Then once you have done this and run strtok on it you need to allocate memory and copy the `token` since strtok modifies the string that is passed to it so every time it returns a pointer, the previous pointer is invalid.

```
temp_list[i] = malloc(strlen(token)+1); 
strcpy(temp_list[i], token);
```

which can also be written as

```
temp_list[i] = strdup(token);
```

Comment: It replaces the delimiter with `'\0'` and that would not cause the observed behavior.

Comment: if used as the OP has it the temp_list pointers will not be valid, and that may explain the behavior. but is true that buf should also be terminated by 0 if used with strtok.

Comment: Yes now I see the code below, your answer is correct then. But very incomplete, since the OP most certainly doesn't know that `strdup()` will use `malloc()` to allocate the buffer in order to copy the string, so mention `free()` please. And point out that undefined behavior will occur because of what is explained in my answer.

Comment: well ur answer is not complete either, even if he were to end buf with 0 the way strtok is used it will cause invalid pointers. he needs both these two fixes. strdup is explained in the linux man so if he found the other functions he is using, he will find that.

Comment: I understand, I am suggesting to complete your answer to delete mine.

Comment: so i should free() the buffer when copying? sorry very new to C

Comment: @jhowe later you need to free all temp_list[i] that you found. safest is to set all pointers to NULL at the start.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to not null-terminating the string you're passing to `strtok_r`, there are some other problems:

- The third argument to `strtok_r` is a context pointer. You should not
  be doing anything with it at all (setting it, expecting it to have a
  certain value, etc.). You should declare it as `char *ctxt` and pass
  it as `&ctxt` (see the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html) for more information).
- When you read    from the file, you're reading 512 bytes at a time, but
  it doesn't seem    like anything is preventing each read from ending
  in the middle of    some value (and then starting in the middle the
  next time). I don't    know what your data looks like, but you should
  probably be reading it    in a different way.

Comment: yes just figured that out any ideas how to tackle that? @Andy Schweig

Comment: What is the format of the data? If it's lines, you can use `fgets` to read a line at a time. Also, if the file isn't too large, you can just `malloc` a buffer of the appropriate size and read the whole thing at once.

Comment: well im supposed to use the open function with a buffer size of 512 i was thinking of clearing the data after the last comma and setting the pointer after that but dont know how to if at all possible (the data has new lines and is separated by commas)